# "I had better go" vs. "I had better be going"

Tags: grammar, difference

Could you tell me what is the slight difference between *I had better go* and *I had better be going*. For example:

> The party is awesome, but **I had better go**. My work starts early in the morning tomorrow.
>
> The party is awesome, but **I had better be going**. My work starts early in the morning tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

When you say: "I had better go"
It implies that you are not doing the party because you
make a decision to go home.

But,when you say: "I had better be going"
It implies that you are still doing the party and think that you should belong to your home at that time.

Comment: We never "do" a party. We "throw" a party, we "hold" a party, we "attend" a party, etc. Though some references may suggest otherwise, it is actually very odd to use it.